# Why the keypress is not work correctly in java

Tags: java, netbeans, keypress

```
private void textFieldNameKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(!textFieldName.getText().isEmpty())  
        buttonFinish.setEnabled(true);
    else 
        buttonFinish.setEnabled(false);
}
```

I just want to control `buttonFinish`'s enable by if there is text in the `textFieldName`.

However, when I test it it always got wrong as when I input 1 letter, the  `setEnabled` won't change.

Only if input more it will be correct. Also when I use backspace, or when clear all letters it won't change `setEnabled` back to false. Only when I click backspace one more time afterwards it will change.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Java & JavaScript are two completely different things.  Removed the unnecessary tag

Answer (score 1):

Try that using key release method.

```
private void textFieldNameKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

When you use the `keyPressed` method, it executes before there is a value or before you delete that value.   Using `keyReleased` it will execute AFTER.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `keyTyped` event instead of `keyPressed`.  That could be giving you trouble because when you press the key, there is no text in the field yet.  That would be why you also get the action to occur when you hit backspace on the last character.  Also make sure your component has the keyboard focus by setting `textFieldName.setFocusable(true);`

Hope this helps